# Creating sprite from texture atlas

Tags: libgdx, sprite, texture-atlas

In my libGdx project,I created a sprite from texture atlas,using createSprite().
I want to implement the sprite as rotated.
How can I do it?Here is my Code:

```
 reelSprite = atlas.createSprite("reel");
```

Inside render():

```
for (Wall lWalls : leftWalls){
        reelSprite.setOrigin(lWalls.getX(), lWalls.getY());
        reelSprite.setRotation(180);

    batch.draw(reelSprite, lWalls.getX(), lWalls.getY());
    }
```

This code is not working.Please tell me what wrong I did.

Comment: Please try to achieve your goals yourself first before asking a question. Then, in the question explain what you tried, with code preferably, and what's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code like this...

```
for (Wall lWalls : leftWalls){
        reelSprite1.setPosition(lWalls.getX(), lWalls.getY());
        reelSprite1.setOrigin(reelSprite1.getWidth()/2,reelSprite1.getHeight()/2);
        reelSprite1.setRotation(180);
        reelSprite1.draw(batch);
```

then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setRotation before you draw the sprite:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setRotation-float-

And even before that set rotation point:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin-float-float-

Comment: I tried both  setRotation() and setOrigin() .But no effect.

Comment: Hmm...I didn't use the sprites, but textures and they are rotating just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
float rotate = 0;
rotate += (sprite.getRotation() - 40) * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
      if(Math.abs(rotate) > 10) // change the number to set the rotation power cap
            {
                rotate = -10;
            }
   sprite.rotate(rotate);
```

Comment: I am moving the reelSprite.Is that the reason rotation not working on the sprite?